# KendoUI Grid - Bulk import/setting of data very slow

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I recently ran into a problem where importing data in bulk and setting the values of the existing rows was taking too long. The usual symptoms were the browser hanging and the "unresponsive script" alert.

Here's the code

```
function import() {
    var dataSource = $("#" + gridId).data("kendoGrid").dataSource;    
    var data = dataSource.data;
    var importedData = null; // from somewhere.....
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].set("column-name-0", importedData[i][0]);
        data[i].set("column-name-1", importedData[i][1]);
    }
}
```

How do i fix this slowness problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "set" method mentioned above is actually a method of the "ObservableObject", which effectively means that each time a set is invoked, it in turn triggers a refresh of the grid. Imagine refreshing the grid for each cell modification in the example above.

A solution would be to not use the set method but to set the new values on the model object directly and then trigger a grid refresh. See below.

```
function import() {
    var grid = $("#" + gridId);
    var dataSource = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;    
    var data = dataSource.data;
    var importedData = null; // from somewhere.....
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i]["column-name-0"] = importedData[i][0]); // the value should be in correct datatype of the column
        data[i]["column-name-1"] = importedData[i][1]);
    }
    grid.refresh();
}
```

Notice that i don't need to play with the 'format' of the column or the 'template' of the column, in case they have been set. The grid refresh automatically takes care of that.

However, do make sure that the datatype of the imported data matches the datatype of the column. If not, the formatters that you have applied will not work.

Hope this helps.